# use "__proto__" as a key in an Object

Tags: javascript, object, properties, prototype

I'm declaring `myDictionary` as an object which is filled by the user (key/ values)
But for the matter of defensive programming, I want to make sure if the user gives `__proto__` as the key to the dictionary object, with the value of `"some value"`, he/she will be able to use it, but as you know when calling `myDictionary.__proto__` the Object prototype setter/getter will be called.
One solution that I've found for this is creating the object with `null` as a prototype, so there will be no `__proto__` setter/getter in its prototype. But the problem is you also won't have the other Object's methods.
I'm longing to see if anyone here can solve the question (any way to polyfill the Object methods while saving the performance?)

---

They try to define the `__proto__` as a key in the dictionary.

```js
let myDictionary = {};

let key = prompt("What's the key?", "__proto__");
myDictionary [key] = "some value";

alert(myDictionary [key]); // [object Object], not "some value"!
```

solving the problem by creating the object with `null` as a prototype:

```js
let myDictionary = Object.create(null);

let key = prompt("What's the key?", "__proto__");
myDictionary[key] = "some value";

alert(myDictionary[key]); // "some value"
```

Or is there a way to assign property with the `__proto__` key without messing with the Object prototype's getter/setter ??

Comment: If you're using an object as a dictionary-type lookup, why not instead use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)? It won't suffer from "reserved" keys.

Comment: @spender looks nice, but the main reason I want it as an Object is to use `Object.prototype` methods such as `toString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a proxy to hide undesired properties in the object.

Since you want to have certain properties with custom values, a map of those can be provided (an object does not work). The return of the `createObject` function will be a new object that checks each key and checks it against the provided map of defined keys. This way you can essentially have custom properties on your object without sacrificing its prototypal methods such as `toString()`.

The implementation of this behavior or done with a Proxy that accepts a getter for each lookup on the object, inside the getter the accessed property is intercepted and if it's defined, that value is returned, otherwise, the normal value is returned.

```js
function protectedObject(target = {}, definedKeys = new Map()) {   
    const handler = {
        get(target, prop) {
            if (definedKeys.has(prop)) return definedKeys.get(prop);
            return target[prop];
        }
    };
    
    return new Proxy(target, handler);
}

const obj = protectedObject({
  test: 123
}, new Map([
  ["__proto__", "some value"]
]));

console.log(obj.test);
console.log(obj.__proto__);
console.log(obj.toString());

alert(obj[prompt("What's the key?", "__proto__")]);
```

All `Object.prototype` methods are intact since this creates a real object (just proxied).

Comment: That's a good approach, but I want to give users the ability to define such a key. Imagine using it as a snippet or smt.

Comment: @Hootan see updated answer

Comment: It looks like an initiative answer. Can you simplify your approach or explain the details in the answer ?? the hierarchy tree looks to be a little complicated. Will I be able to use `Object.prototype` methods on `obj` here? (are Object property methods somewhere in the hierarchy tree?)

Comment: @Hootan Unsure what you mean by "initiative answer" but I updated my answer to explain how this does what you want (provide predefined keys and preserve prototypal methods). The returned object from the function is a real object, it just intercepts the pre-defined keys.

Comment: Great job, But I'm still unsure about your code's performance on server or browser.

Comment: @Hootan there will be a little overhead as expected but nothing too serious, speaking from experience this is unlikely to bottleneck your app since there are no expensive operations, just lookups and a condition. V8 and SpiderMonkey will make quick work JIT compiling this.